# java Error while running class

Tags: java

My directory structure is like this

```
/models/beamCalculate.java
/lib/*.jar     ---------all jar files here.
```

The beamCalculate.java is this --

```
package models;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class beamCalculate{
    private double width;
    private double depth;
    private double M;
    private double Mcap;

public static void main(String args[]){
    ObjectMapper a = new ObjectMapper();
}

}
```

The thing gets compiled with the command --

```
javac -cp "lib/*" models/beamCalculate.java
```

This generates beamCalculate.class file in models/

but when i try to run it using the command --

```
java -cp "lib/*" models/beamCalculate.class i get error -

Error: Could not find or load main class models.beamCalculate.class
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't add `.class` suffix when you run `java` command. Also you shouldn't use `/` in full class name but separate packages with `.`. Try

```
java -cp "lib/*" models.beamCalculate
```

Also you may need to add current location to classpath so maybe try adding `.` to it like

```
java -cp ".;lib/*" models.beamCalculate
```

or

```
java -cp ".:lib/*" models.beamCalculate
```

depending on your Operation System.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
java -cp "lib/*" models.beamCalculate
```